# C++ "system(command)" not working on NetBeans / Windows

Tags: c++, netbeans, system, codeblocks

I am working on a C++ project using CodeBlocks on Windows but then decided to switch to NetBeans IDE 8.2.

Within my project, I am calling another executable file with some passed parameters (I run the other .exe with suitable parameters then I take the output of it to use in my main project), and it used to work on CodeBlocks but not on NetBeans.

The code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "My_Constants.h"
#include "Data.h"
#include "Parameters.h"
#include "Pattern.h"
#include "Squish.h"
#include "Deserializer.h"
#include "Automatic_Run.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Parameters parameters;
    parameters.mode = SQUISH;
    Automatic_Run runner;
    string inputname;

    //--------------------------------User Input-------------------------------------
    cout << "enter input file name \n";
    getline(cin, inputname);
    parameters.inputFileName.assign(inputname);
    cout<<"=============================================================================\n";

    //--------------------------------Running SQUISH/first call--------------------------
    cout<<"Running SQUISH - first call\n";
    char command[1000]="";
    string passedParameters = " -i "+parameters.inputFileName +" -f "+ "t";
    strcat(command,"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\CodeBlocksProjects\\TestSQUISH\\bin\\Debug\\TestSQUISH.exe ");
    strcat(command,passedParameters.c_str());
    int result = system(command);


 // the rest of the code(not relevant to the problem)

    return 0;
}
```

On CodeBlocks, it used to work perfectly and give me the output as a file in the path of my main project (the one I am calling TestSQUISH from). However, now on NetBeans, I am getting the following error:

> sh: C:UsersAdministratorDocumentsCodeBlocksProjectsTestSQUISHbinDebugTestSQUISH.exe: command not found

I checked the terminal of NetBeans to get an idea of what is happening (assuming it might be related) and I noticed that I have to change the path first, then run the executable using:

> ./ TestSQUISH.exe (+parameters)

However, that also didn't work for my project.

Can anyone please suggest a solution or tell me how I can make NetBeans run the command on a Windows terminal as CodeBlocks used to do?

Comment: That is not legal C++. Please provide the exact code you are compiling and executing.

Comment: I guess you need 4x\ instead of 2x\

Comment: Thanks I tried it and it solved the "/" problem, but the main issue with not finding the command is still there:
sh: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\CodeBlocksProjects\TestSQUISH\bin\Debug\TestSQUISH.exe: command not found
@JVApen

Comment: Does the full path to the directory exist? Do the executable file exist?

Comment: Yes sure and the same piece of code was working perfectly on CodeBlocks @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: From the error message, it looks like NetBeans uses `sh` shell (somehow). Are you sure it understands Windows-style path starting with `C:`?

Comment: Yes you're right! I copied the executable to my project's folder and used `strcat(command ,"./TestSQUISH.exe ")` instead of `strcat(command ,"TestSQUISH.exe ")` and it worked. Still trying to find a way to run it from its original folder without copying it. Thanks ! @Yksisarvinen

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project settings and set the project path for execution to be the folder where the other application is.

OR

Set the system path to include that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @Yksisarvinen, I was able to solve the problem.

Noticing that NetBeans uses the shell and not the Windows-style commands and after using the NetBeans own terminal to really get a clear idea of how it translates paths, I was able to run the code successfully using the following:

```
char command[1000]="";
string passedParameters = " -i "+parameters.inputFileName +" -f "+ "t";
strcat(command, "/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator/Documents/CodeBlocksProjects/TestSQUISH/bin/Debug/TestSQUISH.exe ");
strcat(command,passedParameters.c_str());
int result = system(command);
```

Netbeans terminal adds `cygdrive` to the beginning of the path, and uses `c` instead of `C:`.

And in case the executable is in the same directory as your own project then this would be enough:

```
char command[1000]="";
string passedParameters = " -i "+parameters.inputFileName +" -f "+ "t";
strcat(command ,"./TestSQUISH.exe ");
strcat(command,passedParameters.c_str());
int result = system(command);
```